# BLE identifier?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app using `BLE`.
The app must communicate with several types of devices which will have same Services and Characteristics.
The question is, what is the best approach to identify those devices in the scanning stage? How can i **"Categorize"** them already at the scanning?

I read that there is a way to get the `appearance` value, but I didn't find an example of how do I get it from a `BluetoothDevice` object. In another place, I read that I must do the `readCharacteristic()` to receive the `appearance` and I don't want to do that (I don't want to connect at that stage).
I got confused about this.
Please help me to find the right way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data in the `ScanResult` object of your `ScanCallback` like :

```
scanResult.getScanRecord().getDeviceName()
```

or

```
scanResult.getScanRecord().getAddress()
```

Or if you have specific data, read them from bytes :

```
scanResult.getScanRecord().getBytes()
```

Comment: getAddress() is getting the the MAC address and the getDeviceName() giving me a Name. That's not what my question is about.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear on my question.
I have several types of devices like:  Urinal, Basin...

Answer (score 0):

What you mean about categorize? As far as I understood, maybe it is interesting you have a web service that have some devices with their categories and when you got a device during your scanning you can make a GET request in this webservice to check if the device is the one you're looking for

OR

if you have fixed categorized devices you can add them as constants in your app and compare during the scanning